# cannot append parsed string to dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild, domparser

I'm using DOMParser to  parse a string with and html tag to append it on another dom node

```
  window.addEventListener("load",carga);
  var origen = document.getElementById('origen');
  var destino = document.getElementById('destino');

  function carga(e){
    origen.addEventListener('dragstart',function(e){
        e.dataTransfer.setData("Text",origen.outerHTML);
    },false);

    destino.addEventListener('dragover',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    destino.addEventListener('drop',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log( e.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        dragged = parser.parseFromString( e.dataTransfer.getData("Text") , "text/html");
        console.log(dragged);
        destino.appendChild(dragged);
    },false);
  }
```

The content of dragged variable is :

```
<section draggable="true" id="origen" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; border-color: green; border-style: solid;">origen</section>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? You can also append HTML as string without a `DOMParser` with [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: the console error is `TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object`

Comment: Try `var dragged = parser.parseFromString(e.dataTransfer.getData("Text") , "text/html").body.firstElementChild`.

Comment: @af_imi4 I just gave you the explanation in my answer, did you checked it?

Answer (score 6):

Actually when you use **[`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)**'s [**`parseFromString()`** method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Parsing_an_SVG_or_HTML_document) with the option `text/html` it will return a [`HTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) and not a DOM element. So you can't directly append the result to an element, that's why you got `TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object`.

You need to get the content of this `HTMLDocument` before appending it to your Element, this is how you should implement it:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var dragged = parser.parseFromString( "<div><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></div>" , "text/html");

var divDoc = dragged.getRootNode();
destino.appendChild(divDoc.body);
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Example:

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var dragged = parser.parseFromString( "<div><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></div>" , "text/html");

var divDoc = dragged.getRootNode();
document.body.appendChild(divDoc.body);
```

Comment: Or more easily: `destino.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></div>")`

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it's another option, I just tried to point out the `DOMParser` issue, here. :)

Comment: Just curious: Is `getRootNode()` really necessary here? Seems to me `document.body.appendChild(dragged.body)` will work.

Comment: @agrm Yes indeed in this case it's sufficient to call `dragged.body`, but in some cases it can throw an error, that's why we should make sure to get the root node from the parsed `string`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Might be obvious to some but I also noticed this will append the full `<body>` element of the newly parsed divDoc document. Appending `dragged.body.firstChild` can be necessary in some cases.

Comment: @agrm You are welcome, yes it also can be suitable too. :)